# Verify the polynomial of degree $≤ 4$ is exact: $\int_0^1f(x)dx ≈ {1\over90}[7f(0) + 32f({1\over 4}) + 12f({1\over 2}) + 32f({3\over 4}) + 7f(1)]$.

Tags: integration, polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation

Verify that the following formula is exact for polynomial of degree $≤ 4$:
$\int_0^1f(x)dx ≈ {1\over90}[7f(0) + 32f({1\over 4}) + 12f({1\over 2}) + 32f({3\over 4}) + 7f(1)]$.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe Taylor Series

Comment: As a warmup, you might try to prove that $\int_0^1 f(x) \: dx = {1 \over 6} [f(0) + 4f(1/2) + f(1)]$ when $f$ is a polynomial of degree 3 or less.  (This is Simpson's rule for integration.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. As integration and the right hand side are linear in $f$, the quadrature formula is exact for all polynomials of degree $\le 4$ *iff* it integrates the five functions $x \mapsto x^i$, $i = 0,\ldots, 4$ exactly. Just compute the right hand side values for those five $f$ and you are done.